# Solr Fuzzy Search Weird Case

Tags: solr, lucene, fuzzy-search

I am implementing solr fuzzy search using complex phrase query.
But i am phasing a weired case:
`q={!complexphrase}name:"woo~1 grou~2"` return "**wood group**" as a result.
`q={!complexphrase}name:"woo~1 gro~2"` **does not** return "**wood group**".
althouth distance between gro and group is 2!

searching for this query:
`q={!complexphrase}name:"Anderso~1 Interes~2"` returns '**Anderson Interests**'.
duistance between Interes and Interests is same as gro and group!!!

any idea whats the reason?

Comment: Are you using stemming? If yes, check how `gro` is stemmed!

Comment: no i am not using stemming. should i?.

Comment: It depends of your case. Can you add snippets from your schema to see the fieldType of `name`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you are running into a problem with query rewrites.

Any multi-term query (fuzzy queries, prefix queries, etc.) gets expanded, in Lucene, into the exact terms that it matches.  There is a maximum to the number of terms that can be generated this way though, so when rewriting the query, it will just try to pick the best within that limit.  I suspect there are just too many matches for `gro~2`.

Perhaps you'll find it odd that there are so many matches that it can't incorporate all of them into the query.  It looks like you are trying to search for words begining with gro, and with up to two more letters tacked onto the end.  How many could there be?  But that *isn't* what you're searching for.  Fuzzy queries are based on levenshtein distance.  The matches for that term include:

- `g__` -- Three-letter words beginning with g
- `_r_` -- Three-letter words with an r in the middle
- `__o` -- Three-letter words with an o on the end
- `gr__` -- Any four-letter word beginning with gr
- etc.

In short, it could match a *massive* list of terms, and in terms of similarity algorithm, "arm" and "cron" match just as well as "group".

---

If you *really* just want to match terms that start with "gro", use a prefix query instead:  `"woo* gro*"`.

If you want to actually search with a fuzzy query, including the list of possible matches seen above, you can enlarge the `MaxBooleanClauses`, in your [solrconfig's query section](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrConfigXml#The_Query_Section).

```
<query>
  <maxBooleanClauses>1024</maxBooleanClauses>
```

Comment: Thanks. i tried to enlarge MaxBooleanClauses but did not work also!